# To prove that every valuation is a normal domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

This question is from my assignment in commutative algebra and I am struck on it.

> Question: We say that an integral domain A with quotient field K is a valuation ring of K if for every $x\in K$ , $x\neq 0$ if either $x\in A$ or $x^{-1} \in A$. Show that every valuation ring A is a normal domain.

Attempt:  A will be a normal domain if it is integrally closed in it's field of fractions K. I have to show that every element of K which is integral over A lies in A.  Let $x\in K$ is integral over A. Then  $x^n +a_{n-1} x^{n-1} +...+ a_0 =0$ holds with $a_i's \in A$.  Since $x\in K$ , it implies that either $x\in A$ or $x^{-1} \in A$ . If $x\in A$, we are done.

Let $x\in A^{-1}$ . Then $1/x =a_1$ for $a_1 \in A$. But I am not able to think anything concrete from here on.

Can you please help me complete the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $x^{-1}=y$. Clearly $x,y \neq 0$. Suppose that $x \notin A$, then $y \in A$.

Divide (in the field of fractions) the relation
$$x^n + \sum_i a_ix^i=0$$ by $x^n$ to get
$$1=-\sum_i a_i y^{n-i} = y \cdot (\mathrm{something} \in A)$$

This means that $y$ is a unit of $A$, in other words $x \in A$.

Comment: I think you should define from which set you choose x in line 1 of your answer. ie in the line "$ Call x^{-1} =y.$?

Comment: @Avenger I'm using the notation provided in the question. Here $x$ denotes an element of $K$ which is integral over $A$.

Comment: How does y being unit of A implies $x\in A$?

Comment: @Avenger Being a unit means that the inverse of $y$ belongs to $A$. But the inverse of $y$ is $x$, hence $x$ belongs to $A$